# Git: Weird merge conflict when rebasing and dropping a commit

Tags: git

I had a file a.txt with below content

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

This file was commited

Then I added 33 in between 3 and 4 and committed again

Then I added 77 in between 33 and 4 and committed again

Now my history of commited is like this init - 33insert - 77insert

Now I rebased the repo using git rebase -i `init commit id` and dropped the 33insert commit

I was expecting a merge conflict but the conflict was weird

```
1
2
3
<<<< HEAD
=====
33
77
>>>>> 77commit
4
5
```

What I dont understand is 77 commit never had the number 33 in it. So why is it being shown as part of the 77 commit

Comment: A commit is a snapshot of the WHOLE repo. The `77 commit` does include the number 33. `77insert` is the diff between `33 commit` and `77 commit`.

Answer (score 0):

{commitID} before 33insert looks like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

{commitID} of HEAD (when you rebase) looks like:

```
1
2
3
33
77
4
5
```